# Runtime Complexity of Memoization

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

I am struggling to analyze the runtime complexity of the following algorithm formally:

> Given a string s and a dictionary of words dict(wordDict), add spaces in s to
> construct a sentence where each word is a valid dictionary word.
>
> Return all such possible sentences.
>
> For example, given s = "catsanddog", dict = ["cat", "cats", "and",
> "sand", "dog"].
>
> A solution is ["cats and dog", "cat sand dog"].

The proposed algorithm:

```
    wordBreak(s, wordDict) {
        res; //a container used to store the final result.
        if(the length of s is zero or s is invalid) {
            just output res directly.
        }
        if(we have already encountered s before) {
            return the res that s corresponds to.
        }
        if(wordDict contains s) {
            add s to res.
        }
        (looping index from 0 to the length of s) {
            t = the substring of s starting from index to the end of s
            if(wordDict contains t) {
                temp = wordBreak(substring of s from 0 to index , wordDict);
                if(temp is not empty) {
                    (looping index j from 0 to the length of temp) {
                        cancatenate the jth element of temp with t and add it to res.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        store the result of s to storage.
        return res;
    }
}
```

My analysis:

Giving the algorithm, denote the length of $s$ by n. Suppose the runtime complexity is $T(n)$, then we would have something like $T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) + \ldots + T(0) + n + 2^{n-1} - 1$, where I add $n$ because we are looping through $s$. In the meantime we are looping through temp which is a list of results. In the worst case temp can contain $2^{n-1} - 1$ results(subdivisions coming from a string of length $n - 1$). However this does not take into consideration the effect of memoization and I do not know how to achieve that. Specifically my question are:

1. What is the correct time complexity analysis? My guess is that it is at least $n 2^{n-1}$ which is the time taken to create the result list but this is a wild guess without formal proof.
2. How does the analysis differ from the case where there is no memoization.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for computer science SE.

Comment: yes, but I am looking for a mathematically rigorous proof.

Comment: [cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) exists for this purpose. Also I do not think people on this site are familiar with memoization.